# How to log performance in a proper order using Node.js perf_hooks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, profiling

I'm using Node.js [Performance measurement APIs](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) to profile my code, which has the same main functions as [Browser Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance). My code looks like this:

```js
performance.mark('start');

// Use setTimeout to get stable result
setTimeout(() => {
  performance.mark('step1');
  performance.measure('Duration of step 1', 'start', 'step1');

  performance.mark('step2');
  performance.measure('Duration of step 2', 'step1', 'step2');

  performance.mark('step3');
  performance.measure('Duration of step 3', 'step2', 'step3');
  
  // Option 1
  performance.measure('Duration of total', 'start', 'step3');
  
  // Option 2
  performance.measure('Duration of total', 'start');

  // Option 3
  performance.mark('end');
  performance.measure('Duration of total', 'start', 'end');
  
  // "Duration of total" won't appear at the end
  performance.getEntriesByType("measure").forEach((entry) => {
    console.log(`${entry.name}: ${entry.duration} ms`)
  })
}, 100)
```

The result will be something like this:

> Duration of step 1: 111.59999999962747 ms
> Duration of total: 111.69999999925494 ms
> Duration of total: 111.69999999925494 ms
> Duration of total: 111.69999999925494 ms
> Duration of step 2: 0.09999999962747097 ms
> Duration of step 3: 0 ms

I have tried three options, which are actually equivalent, to measure the duration from *'start'* to the end. But the measure `Duration of total` just can't appear at the end when logging measures. I also checked the document of Performance API and found that the return value of `getEntriesByType()` is:

> Returns a list of PerformanceEntry objects in chronological order with respect to performanceEntry.startTime whose performanceEntry.entryType is equal to type.

So once I set the `startMark` of final measure to *'start'*, the measure `Duration of total` will be located right after the measure `Duration of step 1` since they have same `startTime`. However, I need it to log like this, which is more intuitive:

> Duration of step 1: 111.59999999962747 ms
> Duration of step 2: 0.09999999962747097 ms
> Duration of step 3: 0 ms
> Duration of total: 111.69999999925494 ms

**Is there any way to achieve this goal other than manually calculating the total time or switching the positions of measures in the return array?**

Thanks for any solutions or thoughts!

Refs:
[performance.mark](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark)
[performance.measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure)
[performance.getEntriesByType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/getEntriesByType)